# Pass python 3 open file object to C function as FILE *

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I want to pass my file to C function.
I have problem with this. I saw "Segmentation fault"
My C code:

```
// cc -fPIC -shared -o w.so w.c

#include <stdio.h>

void my_writer(FILE *fp, int num) {
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", num);
}
```

My python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#

from ctypes import *

so_file = "./w.so"
my_c_writer = CDLL(so_file)

my_num = 2022

try:
    convert_file = pythonapi.PyObject_AsFileDescriptor
    convert_file.argtypes = [py_object]
    convert_file.restype = c_int

    # fp = open('path').fp     there is no .fp attribute!
    fp = open('num.txt', 'w')
    c_file = convert_file(fp)
    my_c_writer.my_writer(c_file, c_int(my_num))
    fp.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I searched a lot but I found nothing.
The C code file is unchangeable.
I would very appreciate if you help me.

Comment: `PyObject_AsFileDescriptor` returns `int`, not `FILE*`.  Also read the warning [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/file.html) about Python having its own buffering layer, which will interfere with write/read ordering.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark mentioned, `c_file` in your Python module is a file descriptor and not `FILE*`. I was able to get the code to work after I wrote a wrapper function in C.

```c
void my_writer_wrapper(int fildes, int num) {
    FILE *fp = fdopen(fildes, "w");
    my_writer(fp, num);
    fflush(fp);
}
```

Instead of using `my_writer` directly, you can use the wrapper:

```py
...
    fp = open('num.txt', 'w')
    c_file = convert_file(fp)
    my_c_writer.my_writer_wrapper(c_file, c_int(my_num))
    fp.close()
...
```

Comment: My real C code is a library with a lot of FILE * in argument. It is not possible to change all functions or change libray code.
I try this, but it doesn't work:
```
// C code changes
FILE *my_writer_wrapper(int fildes) {
    FILE *fp = fdopen(fildes, "w");
    return fp;
}
```
and finally
```
# Python code changes
my_c_writer.my_writer(my_c_writer.my_writer_wrapper(c_file), c_int(my_num))
```

Comment: I tried to write a function that returns a `FILE*`, and I wasn't able to get it to work either. Can you write a wrapper library that links to the unchangeable library and call the wrapper functions from your Python code?

Comment: I dont know, but i will try it and all other options. Thats good idea. Thanks!